# Statistical test to compare two proportions

Tags: r, meta-analysis, proportion

I am performing a meta-analysis comparing proportions of patients diagnosed with a disease based on 2 different diagnostic criteria.

I have collected and pooled proportions rates (patients with a symptom meeting diagnostic criteria for a certain disease) using a random-effects meta-analysis on R with the meta & metafor packages (using the metaprop function) for studies reporting this proportion with an early diagnostic criteria and similarly for studies with the new criteria.

I am now left with two pooled proportions with a 95%CI for each diagnostic criteria respectively such as:

**Criteria #1 (old):**

Author1, 2000: 3.5%

Author2, 2005: 2.9%

Author3, 2007: 4.9%

*Pooled rate for criteria #1: 3% [95%CI:2-4%]*

**Criteria #2 (new):**

Author4, 2010: 1.1%

Author5, 2011: 0.9%

Author6, 2017: 1.2%

*Pooled rate for criteria #2: 1% [95%CI:0.5-1.5%]*

But I am now unsure which statistical test to use to compare these two proportions and provide a p-value to evaluate whether the new diagnostic test results in a significantly lower proportion of patients being diagnosed.

Thanks.

Comment: See: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates

Comment: Instead of pooling the results use the individual proportions and use a t-test.

Comment: Thank you so much Wolfgang!